# What is the importance of AppData in a Web application

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a website made in react and all the changes I make in this site I always need to clean the AppData, does it always happen in React or do you have a way to bar it?

Comment: What do you mean you need to clean it? Do you mind showing some code if possible please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser may store cached files, cookies, as well as objects persisted with the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) within your AppData directory. You can clear this data by clearing your browsing data from within the browser.